# How to create a custom function snippet in visual studio code javascript snippets?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to create a custom function snippet like this :

```
const handle = () => {

}
```

But when I put it in visual studio code javascript snippets JSON file it gets red underline which means the format is not correct :

[image: javascript.json]

How can I put a custom function snippet with no error in visual studio code user snippets ?

Comment: first read the doc pages of VSC, maybe the squiggles will also tell you what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't have newlines in JSON strings. Instead use `\n` (or `\r\n` on windows).** But VS code expects you to pass different lines as different strings.
So, you can change your body to

```
[
     "const handle = () => {",
     "$0",
     "}"
]
```

**$0** is where your cursor will be if you accept the hint. The pressing tab will take you to **$1, $2, $3, ...**.

Answer (score 1):

JSON `body` is an array so that you can provided multiple lines (array items) comma separated.

```json
"React Function": {
  "prefix" : "f",
  "body": [
     "const handle = () => {",
     "$0",
     "}"
  ],
  "description": "some description"
}
```